# How to make dataframe label a column and split column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr

I have results from a model that I extracted into a dataframe using this code:  `df1 <- coef(summary(mod1))`. My dataframe with the model results has the estimates/model info that I want but the first column isn't registering as a column and is instead the labels for each row.
[image]

Q1) How do I make this first label column into an actual column that will show up when I try `df1$`?

Q2) Once I get this first column to register as a column, I'd like to separate the values at the colon so my dataframe looks like this:

```
LandUse   Enzyme    estimate   se    zval   pval     ci.lb   ci.ub
Ag         acP        0.1      0.5   0.3   7.6e-01   -0.89   1.2
F          acP        0.9      0.4   2.1   2.8e-02    0.1    1.7
H          acP        0.2      0.7   0.2   7.8e-1    -1.2    1.6
```

I was going to use this code from the stringr package to make the above dataframe: `df1 <- str_split_fixed(df1$column1 ":")`
Is this correct for how to split the values in the column or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### base R

```r
df2 <- cbind(strcapture("Land\\.Use([^:]+):Enzyme(.*)",
                        rownames(df1), list(LandUse="", Enzyme="")), df1)
df2
#                      LandUse Enzyme estimate  se zval  pval ci.lb ci.ub
# Land.UseAg:EnzymeacP      Ag    acP      0.1 0.5  0.3 0.760 -0.89   1.2
# Land.UseF:EnzymeacP        F    acP      0.9 0.4  2.1 0.028  0.10   1.7
# Land.UseH:EnzymeacP        H    acP      0.2 0.7  0.2 0.780 -1.20   1.6
```

You can remove the now-redundant row names with `rownames(df2) <- NULL`.

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(estimate = c(0.1, 0.9, 0.2), se = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.7), zval = c(0.3, 2.1, 0.2), pval = c(0.76, 0.028, 0.78), ci.lb = c(-0.89, 0.1, -1.2), ci.ub = c(1.2, 1.7, 1.6)), row.names = c("Land.UseAg:EnzymeacP", "Land.UseF:EnzymeacP", "Land.UseH:EnzymeacP"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the row names to column with `rownames_to_column`, then use `extract` to split the column based on the substring match by capturing

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
   extract('rn', into = c("LandUse", "Enzyme"), "Land.Use(.*):Enzyme(.*)")
```

-outut

```
LandUse Enzyme estimate  se zval  pval ci.lb ci.ub
1      Ag    acP      0.1 0.5  0.3 0.760 -0.89   1.2
2       F    acP      0.9 0.4  2.1 0.028  0.10   1.7
3       H    acP      0.2 0.7  0.2 0.780 -1.20   1.6
```

Comment: Thank you so much!